# Google Translate API Disable Transliterations

Tags: php, google-translate

I am using the Google translate API and it returns a translation "panthafmaste" from "πανθαυμαστε". Is there any way that I can get a null value instead so that I know that this word was not translated?

I tried detecting the language, but the precision is returned always as "1" and "isReliable=false". It might be possible to transliterate it via Google and compare, but I see that it is deprecated.

```
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_TranslateService.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Translate PHP Starter Application');



    // Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=translate to generate your
    // client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
    // $client->setDeveloperKey('insert_your_developer_key');
    $service = new Google_TranslateService($client);


    $translations = $service->translations->listTranslations($word, $this->google_translate_to,Array('source'=>$this->google_translate_language));//$this->google_translate_to);
```

Comment: Can you add your code in question?

Comment: I have added, but I don't think it will help unless you are familiar or become familiar with the API.